# CS50 pset5 hashtable check issue

Tags: c, cs50

My task is to implement a program that will lode a dictionary into a data structure, and spellcheck it. I have managed to do it with a simple linked list, but I get wrong results when i try to use a hashtable. I get way to much misspelled words I have no idea whats wrong.

```
 typedef struct node
{
char word[LENGTH+1];
struct node *next;
}
node;
node *hashtable[150000] = {NULL};
```

the check function:

```
int i = hash(word);
node *cursor = hashtable[i];

while(cursor!=NULL)
{
    if(strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0)
   {
       return true;
   }
  else
    {
      cursor = cursor->next;
   } 
}
return false;
```

I have tried setting w->next to NULL, and it made absolutely no difference. So i got rid of it.

The load into hashtable

```
// open dictionary file and ensure it worked
FILE *d = fopen(dictionary, "r");
if(d==NULL)
{ 
    printf("File wont open");
    return false;
};


// initiate loop for putting all words into array, untile the end of dictionary.
while(fscanf(d, "%s", word) != EOF)
{
    //create a new node and ensure it worked
    node *w = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(w ==NULL)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    //coppy word from dictionary to node. w->word is a pointer to char in a node created above.
    strcpy(w->word, word);

    //get hash code and stor in i.
    long i = hash(word);


    //place the node in hashtable in correct place.
    if(hashtable[i]->next==NULL)
    {
        hashtable[i]->next = w;
    }
    else
    {
        w->next = hashtable[i]->next;
        hashtable[i]->next = w;
    }
}
fclose(d);
return true;
```

And a hashfunction:

```
long hash = 0;

    for (int counter = 0; str[counter]!='\0'; counter++)
    {
        hash = (str[counter] + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash)%150000;//150000=size of hashtable
    }
    return hash;
```

Comment: What does a `node` look like, and how do you initialize its members? After `malloc` there are no guarantees that `w->next` is `NULL`, for example. And is `w->word` a pointer or a `char` array? You can edit the question to add some more info.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that strcasecmp in check function, was case sensitive.
According to [this site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcasecmp.html) it shouldn't be.

After I manually changed all characters to lower case in the word to be checked, everything works as it should.